# Outer Coordinates for ImageMap

Tags: javascript, html, coordinates, imagemap

I have an Image Map like below, One Place inside another as follows:

[image]

How to get the Coordinates for Outer place without selecting inside. I'm using this [**Link**](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/s/u/summerstyle/365ccfd644f2b008c33f0046d2ba1a8f/summer-html-image-ma_1355318513_demo_package/index.html) to get the coordinates of the map.

(i.e i need to get UpperHanover's coordinates along when hovered on the three areas it should not show Upperhanover.)

I want get coordinates for the outer area without selecting inside area as follows.
[image]

As per suggested answer below i'm getting image map as folloes: but i dont want  to see the border line.
[image]

Sorry for my poor explanation. Please ask if you are not able to understand.

Comment: Could you simply split the red area up into two areas that - put together - enclose the white area?

Comment: @icke Can you please elaborate it..

Comment: Adding my suggestion as an answer

Comment: Do using Dreamweaver to mapping image?

Answer (score 3):

I would try to use a "poly" shaped area that encloses the white area.

```
<img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png" usemap="#example"/>
<map name="example">
  <area shape="poly" coords="0,0, 280,0, 280,50, 250,50, 250,150, 320,150, 320,50, 280,50, 280,0, 538,0, 538,190, 0,190" alt="clickable area" href="javascript:alert('Click!')">
</map>
```

I have created a JSFiddle as an example. The yellow "o" of the logo is not clickable while the rest is. http://jsfiddle.net/pXth7/

I hope I understood your problem correctly.

**Edit**: I did not understand it correctly. Apparently you want to make the clickable areas visible with some library or other. The only solution to that I can think of is this: http://jsfiddle.net/X4mPW/10/

Comment: This idea when implemented, i got the result as follows [**image link**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mQmKS.png)

Comment: This will create a border line while highlighting with colors

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/pXth7/2/ has your image with only the outer area clickable. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: yes that's fine but when i colored, I'm getting like that [**Link**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mQmKS.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "colored"? Also this is not something you would obtain from the link I provided, as the area I selected there was not as detailed. Perhaps you mixed up my answer with the one by Crozin?

Comment: Unless you are using something like JQuery maphilight you're not going to see the image map at all. What are you using to make the map visible?

Comment: See your answer with this jsfiidle http://jsfiddle.net/X4mPW/7/... I just dont want that line which connecting inner and outer place

Comment: Agreed, there's a red line because you showed the image map. I dont believe it can be done my way if visible image maps are a requirement. I would try to go with an adaptation of prakashstar42's suggestion. Also you should probably update your question to reflect that the image map is going to be made visible with maphilight.

Answer (score 2):

You could create two separate shapes for a single map:

```
<img src="EFPvH.png" alt="" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="30, 126, 19, 56, 80, 52, 103, 68, 106, 62, 127, 75, 145, 74, 176, 96, 174, 71, 188, 71, 188, 142, 93, 145, 91, 120" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="16, 7, 185, 9, 188, 67, 178, 67, 173, 65, 148, 64, 123, 49, 91, 37, 83, 53, 22, 55" />
</map>
```

First shape covers Upper Upper Hanover, and second shape covers Lower Upper Hanover.

[image]

Comment: This idea when implemented, i got the result as follows [**image link**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mQmKS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the link I have given link 1 to entire logo and link 2 to  red color 'O'

http://jsfiddle.net/pXth7/1/

```
<img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png" usemap="#Map"/>
<map name="Map"><area shape="circle" coords="179,97,60" href="javascript:alert('Click 1')">
  <area shape="rect" coords="42,16,472,167" href="javascript:alert('Click 2')" >
</map>
</map>
```

Comment: Both link in the same image

Comment: @UdhayaKumar Have you checked my jsfiddle link ?

Answer (score 1):

From what you have said, I have the impression that

1. You want to see information when you hover UpperHanover (the coordinates of the area?), but not when you hover the smaller inside areas.
2. You don't want to see a focus line around the area when you click it.

I have forked the JSFiddle of icke to solve both issues here: http://jsfiddle.net/ACjBQ/1/

(1.) is solved by adding a `title` attribute to the `<area>` tag with the contents that you want to have. I just copied the value of the `coords` attribute but you can substitute any text of your choosing. (2.) is solved by adding some JQuery code that un-highlights the area as soon as you click it.

Please let us know whether this is what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Image maps are not really for coloring, but is this what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/X4mPW/8/

```
<area shape="rect" coords="240,45,330,140" alt="UPPER HANOVER TOWNSHIP">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,538,190" alt="UPPER HANOVER TOWNSHIP" href="javascript:alert('Click!')">
```

Comment: This is the result with your answer http://jsfiddle.net/X4mPW/9/ ... The inner part also colored... I dont want that

Comment: That's impossible with image maps. But you could fake it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/X4mPW/11/